# MLE estimator and sufficient statistic

Tags: maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

Is it generally true that for the exponential family the MLE estimate will be the sufficient statistic divided by the number of data points?
It seems to be true for a couple of examples, but I am not well versed enough in the theory of exponential families to prove this to myself.

**Bernoulli Example**

Sufficient Statistic: $$T(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
MLE: $$\frac{1}{n}T(X)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, under a certain parameterization. Choose $T(X)$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mu T(X) = \mu$. Then the likelihood of $X_1, \dots, X_i$ is 
$$ \log P_\mu(\mathbf{X}) = \text{const} + \big<\mu,\sum_i T(X_i) \big> - n \,A(\mu),$$ 
so
$$\nabla_\mu \log P_\mu(\mathbf{X})= \sum_i T(X_i) - n\nabla_\mu A(\mu)$$ 
and a necessary first-order condition for the MLE $\hat{\mu}$ is 
$$n^{-1} \sum_i T(X_i) = \nabla_\mu A(\hat{\mu}).$$
The function $A(\mu)$ is called the *log-partition function* and has the property that $$\nabla_\mu A(\mu) = \mathbb{E}_\mu T(X),$$
so by our choice of $T$ we get the desired relationship.

The reason you have noticed this in several examples is that many distributions (including Bernoulli, multinomial, and Poisson) are traditionally written in this form. But it is possible to reparameterize any (minimal) exponential family in such a way; see [Jordan's lecture notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf) for more details.